# Does the Hale / Snowdon' surname mean anything?

Tags: pokemon

From "Spell of the Unown: Entei", a.k.a "劇場版ポケットモンスター　結晶塔の帝王　ＥＮＴＥＩ Pocket Monsters the Movie - Emperor of the Crystal Tower: Entei"

Does the Hale / Snowdon' surname mean anything?

Molly's original name was Mii / Me, for the first-person singular pronoun, with her father being Spencer / Sully...

...

Is it a reference to the "snowy" / Icy / Crystalline environment that Greenfield turns into? If so, is there a clear reference? Like a character saying that it looks like snow / ice / etc?